# Archive Cordova Project - Path does not exist: www

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode-archive

I am trying to submit a iOS iPhone/iPad Cordova project to the App Store through XCode.

I am able to build the app successfully on all simulators and devices. When I try to archive the app, I get an error.

```
Shell Script Invocation Error - Path does not exist: www
```

So for some reason, my Shell Script called in my project's Build Phases is not able to find my 'www' folder.

The closest I have gotten to solving, is I heard Archive uses a different directory structure when archiving. In which I've tried to add

```
 "$(PLATFORM_NAME)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include/"
```

to the User Header Search Paths, but that did not solve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if you don't have full cordova project and only have ios folder from platforms and your www folder is located as ios/{your_app_name_folder}/www

**Solution : move www folder from 'ios/{your_app_name_folder}/www' to 'ios/www'**

Answer (score 3):

For new apps or upgraded projects run `cordova build ios` and it should move/create the WWW folder inside of platform/ios/